# storing ldap password configuration file

Tags: java, passwords, ldap, store, config

I have to connect with ldap.I want to store user id and password in configuration file.What is the best way to store password in  config file, so it is secured?

i dnt want to use spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the password with MD5 and re-write the config file updating the password with encrypted one. Make sure to have necessary checks before you do so, like if the password is already encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

**Property file**

If you want to use java without thrills I would opt for a property file and load it from the class path. 
Depending on in what context you are using it, the class path might differ.
see http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

As a security I always limit the read-write-execute properties of the configuration file as much as possible.
E.g. only the tomcat user and admin users for web applications.

**Database**

Storing in a database is a better alternative if you want it to be maintainable via the application itself. However you probably might resort to using property files for storing your database credentials.

Comment: if the property file is on a client machine yes, but then the only way is to hand out a 'client user'.. if it is on a server machine you can limit read/write access to a user which only you and other people you trust has access to